# avoid the double counting in for loop

Tags: python

This is my situation, I have 16 tuples inside a list. I need to match one of the element of tuple and iterate the list. it should return me the unique set but its returning me double or triple counts. Any list comprehension advise in this?

```
lst= [(12, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (17, 'a'), (12, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (23, 'b'), (12, 'b'), (18, 'b'), (12, 'b'), (12, 'b'), (15, 'a'), (12, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (24, 'c'), (12, 'c')]
```

I need to access this list from above,

```
for i in  employerEmployeeEdges:
""iterate over the list of tuples""
    for j in employerEmployeeEdges[1:]:
"""iterate over to the next tuple to check if that matches
        if i[1]==j[1]:
            print(i[1], j[1))
```

I know I have partially accomplished to match the items but how would I prevent it double counting?

Comment: from collections import Counter, using Counter to count all elements in your list. And get what you want.

Comment: Well what's as desired

Comment: What would be the exact result you would want to get with that test case?

Comment: Your inner loop loop always starts `j` at the second element; I suspect you instead want it to start from one beyond the current position of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what output you want from your question, but I'll interpret it as such:

```
lst= [(12, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (17, 'a'), (12, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (23, 'b'), (12, 'b'), (18, 'b'), (12, 'b'), (12, 'b'), (15, 'a'), (12, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (24, 'c'), (12, 'c')]

unique_ele = set([l[1] for l in lst])
summed_tuples = [(sum([l[0] for l in lst if l[1] == ele]), ele) for ele in unique_ele]  # [(77, 'b'), (36, 'c'), (128, 'a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give only unique tuples:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.unique(lst, axis=0)
z = [] 
for i in y:
   z.append(tuple(i))
```